# Infer type T using type assertion of other type which is conditioned on T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider this function that retrieves either an "item" or an array of "items":

```
function foo<T extends Item | Item[]>(id: T extends Item ? string : undefined): T {
  ...
}
```

The purpose of this is that you call `foo` with an `id` if you want a single item, or without an `id` if you want an array of items. This works well so that the caller may do:

`foo<MyItem>('42')`

and

`foo<MyItem[]>(undefined)`

(One could make this even better using varags such as `function foo<T extends Item | Item[]>(...[id]: T extends Item ? [string] : []): T {` to enable calling `foo` without arguments when retrieving an array).

However, inside the implementation of `foo`, I noticed that if I put a check for the type of `id`:

```
if (id) { // if typeof id === 'string' gives same result
  ...
}
```

... then in that if clause, the compiler does not understand that the type `T` must now extend `Item` and *not* `Item[]` (due to `id` being a string only if `T extends Item`. I still need to do `T as Item` if I want to call any code that relies on T being an `Item`, or I will get a:

`TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Item'.   Type 'Item | Item[]' is not assignable to type 'Item'.     Property 'id' is missing in type 'Item[]' but required in type 'Item'.`

In other words, the type of `id` is conditioned on the type of `T`, but the type of T is not inferred back/narrowed by asserting that `id` is a string.
Is it possible to solve this somehow? It's an easy `as` cast, but I'm simply curious.

Comment: See [the GitHub issues linked here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995#issuecomment-797511473) for info.  You can't narrow `T` by a check of `id` because `T` might be the full `Item | Item[]` union.  You want to say that "`T extends Item` OR `T extends Item[]`" instead of `T extends Item | Item[]`, but there's no facility in TS to express this.  You should just use a type assertion to suppress errors if you're not concerned about such possibilities.

Comment: I think it is better to avoid heterogeneous unions. But it is only my opinion

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you want a function to return different things depending on the passed arguments.

This is a job better suited for [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

```
type Item = {};

function foo<T extends Item>(): T[];
function foo<T extends Item>(id: string): T;
function foo<T extends Item>(id?: string): T | T[] {
  const item = {} as T; // for demo purpose only

  if (id){
    return item;
  }

  return [item];
}

const test1 = foo();      // Item[]
const test2 = foo('1');   // Item
```

Check the [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8C+BuAUDgZgK4B2AxsAJYD2xU+VVAPACpQQAe8xAJgM6zwEAPgAUASgBcUZgG0AuriJlKNOgxZtOEHvziJRFblN7AAThWIBzSdMUly1WvSasOXPgP0jDAfmNmLaylWAB9peXQcKChSGhMoCkEUdAwoAEN+ZiwoAHoctVMobkQqKDBCUzAqXmgaABsQPGiKfChvbjE0KOioUwhgCtpExFxojCbe-sGoGWGEBRxxnFjiePgTAEZk53Fsnui8zwR5ZbjgKHXgACZthhEAcg37sT3c-L0EIA).

As a general rule of thumb, use overloads if your typing logic involves function implementation. [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) are usually more useful when defining types or interfaces that don't deal with runtime logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the return type conditional on the argument type, instead of the other way around:

```
function foo<T extends string | undefined>(id: T): T extends string ? Item : Item[] {
  // ...
}
```

Or if you will only ever want to call it with something that is either definitely a string or definitely undefined, you can use overloads and not make it generic at all: this way you can call the function without an argument, instead of passing `undefined` as an argument.

```
function foo(): Item[];
function foo(id: string): Item;
function foo(id?: string): Item | Item[] {
  // ...
}
```

The practical difference between these solutions is that using overloads, your function can't be called with an argument of type `string | undefined`, so it's always known at compile-time whether a particular call will resolve to a single item or an array of items.

Note that both solutions avoid the problem of calling your function with a type parameter like `Item & HTMLCanvasElement` and then having an unsound return type.